# How to add a custom field in Civicase that can be retrieved later?

Tags: drupal, custom-fields, webform-civicrm, civicase, 4.7

My question sounds simple, but... to explain. We are using Civicase to manage mentoring.  I want to add from 1 to 6 mentoring goals for each case - these would be text fields individual to each case.  When the mentoring is completed (months later) the goals are then 'picked' as ones which best matched to our funder's 4 targets. My problem is that I can't see a custom field to hold these goals that would do this or just lack the imagination on how to manipulate Civi to achieve this! I'm using 4.7 with Drupal, have about 5 years Civi experience but prefer not to code. Would a webform be the answer? Maybe I just create 6 text fields, each one with an associated drop down select with the funder's targets - but that seems a bit clumsy.  It seems that what I need to do is to allow the user to enter data into a select box, but that doesn't seem possible with custom fields.

Answer (score 1):

One answer is to create a set of fields, set to use for 'cases', then add your six text fields to that set, then set up a webform that is set to Create or Edit a Case, and display those fields.

That said, I can't quite picture your use-case.

You say "Maybe I just create 6 text fields, each one with an associated drop down select with the funder's targets".

It may help if you can provide a specific example in your question.

Comment: I've created a custom field set for each mentoring goal, and if there are just 3/4 goals this seems to work, so I can have other fields added to those sets.  Thanks for the suggestion!